# Do we need to add livedata when we are authenticating some user?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, observer-pattern, android-livedata

I am new to android and also in this MVVM pattern, I saw some tutorial that the livedata is being used there to fetch the userdata and check authenticated user in some session related class. As per my understanding livedata is used when some data is needed to be updated listening the changes for implementing the observable pattern. I used kotlin Coroutines for fetching the user response here:

```
Coroutines.main {
            try {
                val loginresponse = repository.userLogin(email!!, password!!)
                loginresponse.token.let {
                    val keys = listOf("TOKEN", "USERNAME", "USERID")
                    val values = listOf(
                        loginresponse.token,
                        loginresponse.username,
                        loginresponse.id.toString()
                    )
                    repository.saveUserInfo(prefs, keys, values)
                    authListener?.onSuccess(it)
                    val intent = Intent(mContext, Sos::class.java)
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
                    mContext.startActivity(intent)
                }
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                authListener?.onFailure(e.toString())

            } catch (e: NoInternetException) {
                authListener?.onFailure(e.message!!)
            }
}
```

Is it ok to use coroutines or should I modify user with livedata to use it in some session managing class ?